# How to specify delimiter for list.each function in ColdFusion 11?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11

I have adopted the CFScript syntax for most of the work with ColdFusion now, since with the new version of ColdFusion v11(codenamed Splender), almost all the short-comings of the script style syntax has been given serious thoughts. Thought suprisingly, I came across a requirement where I needed to iterate throught the list with variable delimiter. So I choose the `list.each` function in CF11 and not any other option would do since I also need the current index value along the way as well.

```
list.each(function(element,index,list){
    writeOutput("#index#:#element#;");
}, ";")
```

The problem is that this function surprisingly does not seem to support a custom delimiter.
To save the time, I would like to mention that I already tried the `for (element in...)` with a count variable for my needs.

```
var idx=1;
for (element in "a,b,c,d,e"){
    writeOutput(element);
    LOCAL.idx++;
}
```

But I would appreciate some help with the original `list.each` function in CF11, is it even possible somehow to implement? or is it what I think a shortcoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not using CF11, but i would point you to this [bug report](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3845963), which seems to say the HF3 does exactly what you want.

If that doesn't work, or in the meantime, you could convert it to an array and use `ArrayEach()`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out that it is a bug indeed. For the solution, I tried converting it to an array and it solves the problem. But I wanted to make sure I am not missing something with the list.each function.